# Middle/Vertical alignment doesn't work with table of images

Tags: tables, graphics

I have a table of pictures with labels beside each row. I'd like to to have those labels be vertically aligned with their corresponding image. Every solution I've found and tried has failed. See MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
% set width for all the figures    
\newlength{\recircfigwidth}
\setlength{\recircfigwidth}{3cm}

\begin{figure*}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
   \centering
\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}|ccc}
\multirow{2}{*}{\(\phi\ [^\circ]\)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Swirl Strength [\%]} \\ \cline{2-4} 
                          & 100           & 150          & 200          \\ \hline
15  & 
\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} & 
\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} \\
12.5 &\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} \\
10 &\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image}             
\end{tabular}

   \caption{Caption for the whole figure}
    \label{fig:fig1} % I can do without the label too
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aligned with the vertical center of the row of images?

Comment: @egreg Yes, I've updated to question to be more explicit. Would that also not be the middle of the cells? Or is cell height independent of the image height (somehow...)?

Comment: `m` is not doing what you think it does, it is aligning the vertical centre of the text in the first column with the reference point of the row which is the baseline of the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `adjustbox`. I define a `\fixedincludegraphics` command that states the width once and for all, but also allows further keys; for this application, `valign=c`.

I also removed the vertical rule that does nothing good.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

% set width for all the figures    
\newlength{\recircfigwidth}
\setlength{\recircfigwidth}{3cm}
\newcommand{\fixedincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth,#1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\toprule
\(\phi\) (\(^\circ\)) & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Swirl Strength (\%)} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4} 
& 100           & 150          & 200          \\
\midrule
15  & 
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image} & 
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image} &
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image} \\
\addlinespace
12.5 &
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image} &
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image} &
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image} \\
\addlinespace
10 &
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image} &
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image} &
\fixedincludegraphics[valign=c]{example-image}             
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption for the whole figure}
    \label{fig:fig1} % I can do without the label too
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to also add the `valign=c` option into the definition of `\fixedincludegraphics` in order to avoid repeatedly having to add `valign=c`?

Comment: @leandriis The `\fixedincludegraphics` command is probably also useful in other contexts.

Comment: So you mention `adjustbox` as the (seemingly) primary operator in the solution, but it doesn't actually appear in the solution (apart from the package import). Is it simply used automatically by the `\includegraphics` command, or is it doing soemthing somewhere else?

Comment: @u2berggeist `adjustbox` provides the `valign` key, that's not available with the default `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multirow, makecell}

    \begin{document}
    % set width for all the figures
    \newlength{\recircfigwidth}
    \setlength{\recircfigwidth}{3cm}

    \begin{figure*}
        \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
       \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{1cm}|XXX}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\(\phi\ [^\circ]\)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Swirl Strength [\%]} \\ \cline{2-4}
                              & 100 & 150 & 200 \\ \hline
    15 & \includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} \\
    12.5 &\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} \\
    10 &\includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=\recircfigwidth]{example-image}
    \end{tabularx}

       \caption{Caption for the whole figure}
        \label{fig:fig1} % I can do without the label too
    \end{figure*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]